# Unexpected INSERT ... SET query behavior

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a table where I need to store two id's from another table. While doing some debugging I noticed some strange behavior of SQL.

Example of wrong sql:

```
INSERT INTO follower_list set `followerUserId` = '3' AND `followingUserid` = '4'
```

The above query was inserting the zero's as value in DB. I studied the query closer and realized I had made a mistake of putting `and` in place of `,`. The real query I need to fulfill my purpose is:

```
INSERT INTO table SET col1 = '3' , col2 = '4'
```

Which worked as I expected. My question is related to the first (incorrect) query - since it executed and is syntactically correct, where would queries like it be used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why the `INSERT` statement doesn't generates syntax error and it is also working is because `MySQL` implicitly (*one thing I don't like in MySQL `:D`*) parses the statement as boolean expression.

In your `INSERT` statement, only `followerUserId` column is *updatable* because the rest are part of the boolean expression. The query was evaluated as:

```
INSERT INTO follower_list SET followerUserId = ('3' and (followingUserid='4'))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*SELECT statement*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d82c/1)

here:

```
followerUserId = ('3' and (followingUserid='4')) // assuming followingUserid <> 4
followerUserId = ('3' and (0))
followerUserId = 0
```

another,

```
followerUserId = ('3' and (followingUserid='4')) // assuming followingUserid = 4
followerUserId = ('3' and (1))
followerUserId = 1      // will only return zero if one of the values is zero
```

Comment: you sir are the jon skeet of sql .. amazing knowledge.

Comment: Thanks @JW Today I also learn `Insert` with `SET` and `AND` :)

Comment: @YogeshSuthar it's an old syntax of `INSERT` in mysql.

Comment: @JW. Yeah I know how to use `SET` with `INSERT`, but don't know `SET` with `AND` in `INSERT`.